# Apache TIME_WAIT connections, php on solaris 11.2

Tags: php, apache, joomla, solaris

I have a server with apache server with php.

- S.O. Solaris 11.2
- Apache 2.2
- PHP 5.3.28
- RAM 20G
- 16 cores

In apache I have configured 40 domains, with the following characteristics:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    LogFormat       "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" **%T/%D**" combined_t
    ErrorLog        "|/usr/apache2/2.2/bin/rotatelogs  /opt/avv2002_data/logs/domain_err.%Y%m%d 86400"
    CustomLog       "|/usr/apache2/2.2/bin/rotatelogs  /opt/avv2002_data/logs/domain_log.%Y%m%d 86400" combined_t
    LogLevel  info
    DocumentRoot "/opt/www/apache/joomla/sites/"
   DirectoryIndex index.htm index.html index.php
    <Directory "/opt/www/apache/joomla/sites/">
        Options -Indexes FollowSymlinks Includes MultiViews
AllowOverride All
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^.*$ index.html [NC,L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

A few days ago development uploaded a new application in PHP and my server started with problems with ram and cpu, looking a bit I found the following:

too many process, children and TIME_WAIT.

example:

use swap.

extract swap with pmap

swap: 212276 bytes  pid: 23158

```
# ps auxww | grep 23158

webservd 23158  0.1  0.121227628216 ?        S 11:49:57  0:06 /usr/apache2/2.2/bin/httpd -k start
```

see too many TIME_WAIT

```
netstat -aun | grep 23158

serverip.80      serverip.61768   root      23158 httpd           44876      0   65160      0 TIME_WAIT
serverip.80      serverip.31254   root      23158 httpd            7843      0   65160      0 TIME_WAIT
serverip.80      serverip.55937   root      23158 httpd            7262      0   65160      0 TIME_WAIT
serverip.80      serverip.52572   root      23158 httpd            4845      0   65160      0 TIME_WAIT
serverip.80      serverip.49687   root      23158 httpd            7075      0   65160      0 TIME_WAIT
serverip.80      serverip.29891   root      23158 httpd           29310      0   65160      0 TIME_WAIT
serverip.80      serverip.57332   root      23158 httpd            9557      0   65160      0 TIME_WAIT
serverip.80      serverip.20296   root      23158 httpd            7262      0   65160      0 TIME_WAIT
serverip.80      serverip.16077   root      23158 httpd           61246      0   65160      0 TIME_WAIT

.......


netstat -aun | grep "ipserver.80" | wc -l
2077

ps auxww | grep "/usr/apache2/2.2/bin/httpd -k start" | wc -l
507
```

my apache server status show full wwwwwwwwwwwww

```
pache Server Status for serverip

Server Version: Apache/2.2.27 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.27 OpenSSL/1.0.1h DAV/2 PHP/5.3.28 mod_fcgid/2.3.9
Server Built: Jun 17 2014 11:19:37
Current Time: Wednesday, 05-Apr-2017 13:50:10 CDT
Restart Time: Wednesday, 05-Apr-2017 13:12:10 CDT
Parent Server Generation: 0
Server uptime: 38 minutes
Total accesses: 125046 - Total Traffic: 3.6 GB
CPU Usage: u404.25 s342.99 cu0 cs0 - 32.8% CPU load
54.8 requests/sec - 1.6 MB/second - 30.4 kB/request
29 requests currently being processed, 0 idle workers

WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWwWWWWWW
```

Is there any way to see which domain is the one with a lot of traffic? In this way you could know exactly what was what the team of development modified

I was thinking of a profiler of php, to see which domain is taking longer

Any idea what else I should check?

Comment: Cross-posted:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356224/apache-time-wait-connections-w-sending-reply-and-php-on-solaris-11-2

Answer (score 0):

You have reached the maximum number of workers, you will need to increase it. We have posted a guide on [how to increase the max number of Apache workers on WHM](http://www.itoctopus.com/your-joomla-website-is-really-really-slow-maybe-you-hit-the-maximum-number-of-apache-clients), in your case, you will need to do this manually in the configuration file of Apache (change your MaxClients to 1024).

Now the question is, why did you reach the maximum number of workers, is it because real traffic, or is it because of something else?

My advice is to check the Apache logs (I don't know what the structure is on Solaris, the last time I worked on it was back in 2004) and see which website is having the most traffic (it is the traffic with the biggest log). You should then analyze that traffic: Is it real traffic? Is it bot traffic? If it is bot traffic, then is it legitimate bot traffic (if not, then you should block all those illegitimate bots)?

If it is real traffic, then do you have a lot of 404s? If yes, then you need to address those 404s - because each 404 will need another worker in a Joomla instance.

Comment: I modified the settings, and even so it drops once a day (before it was every 5 minutes). No database is used, so I think it should be some php script, however I have no way to see which domain it is, since I have configured many domains. This is my apache configuration:     StartServers         10
    MinSpareServers       25
    MaxSpareServers      500
    ServerLimit          1400
    MaxClients           1400
    MaxRequestsPerChild   1000

Comment: Have you checked the Apache logs to see which one has the biggest log size?